# суммирование по индексам Numpy вектора

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, индексация

Нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает сумму значений массива по списку индексов элементов. Например: массив(2 5 7 3), список индексов(1 3), ответ(2+7=9).
Не могу разобраться, как мне сделать суммирование по индексам.
Остановился на этом:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(input('Введите значения массива: ').split()).astype(int)

indices = np.array(input('Введите индексы элементов в массиве: ').split()).astype(int)

result = 0

for i in indices:
    result += arr[indices[i]]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все просто:

```
In [42]: a = np.array([2, 5, 7, 3])

In [43]: idx = np.array([1,3])

In [44]: a[idx]
Out[44]: array([5, 3])
```

только индексирование в Numpy (как и в обычном Python) начинается с `0`:

```
In [45]: a[idx-1]
Out[45]: array([2, 7])

In [46]: a[idx-1].sum()
Out[46]: 9

In [47]: a[idx].sum()
Out[47]: 8
```

**UPDATE:**

> как сделать, чтоб индексы вводить не в массив, а в список?

```
In [48]: idx = [0,2]

In [49]: a[idx].sum()
Out[49]: 9
```

правда трюк с вычитанием числа от всех элементов списка уже не сработает:

```
In [50]: idx-1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-a656c3318499> in <module>()
----> 1 idx-1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

можно так:

```
In [52]: a[np.array(idx)-1].sum()
Out[52]: 8
```

Почему в Numpy лучше пользоваться встроенными "vectorized ufuncs":

```
In [62]: a = np.random.randint(10**4, size=(10**6), dtype=np.int32)

In [63]: a.shape
Out[63]: (1000000,)

In [64]: idx = np.random.randint(10**6, size=(10**4))

In [65]: %timeit a[idx].sum()
50.9 µs ± 907 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [66]: %timeit sum(a[i] for i in idx)
3.78 ms ± 287 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо большое. А я почему-то прибавлял единицу, а не отнимал :D
Скажите еще, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтоб индексы вводить не в массив, а в список?

Comment: В виде списка (list).

Answer (score 2):

Если доработать алгоритм в вопросе:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array('1 2 4 8'.split()).astype(int)
indices = np.array('0 2'.split()).astype(int)
    
result = 0
for i in indices:
    result += arr[i]

# OR:

result = sum(arr[i] for i in indices)
print(result)
```

---

Ошибка в том, что `for i in indices` уже возвращал значения, а не индексы. Поэтому у автора `indices` возвращал значения и внутри цикла у `indices` бралось значение по самому значение, которое было индексом.

Comment: мне кажется - вся "прелесть" Numpy как раз в векторизованных (быстрых) функциях. Иначе нет особого смысла использовать Numpy...

Comment: Все то же самое можно сделать и со списком индексов, верно?

Comment: @MaxU, согласен, поэтому вашему ответу плюс поставил :)

Comment: @РоманОкс, да, генератор или список в данном случае не имеет значения :)

Comment: но ведь ответ то правильный! :-D